# WMI-filter on GPO evaluates contradictory

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, wmi

**Background information**

I have got several, very basic, WMI filters that I use for my GPOs. All they do is check for the running operating system version and the value of an environment variable.

[image]

This filter is being used on several machines across our domain without any issues. But about a handfull of them do not reliably evaluate this WMI filter and even provide **contradictory** results!

Have a close look at the following screenshot taken from a RSOP created by `gpresult /h rsop_computer.html /scope computer`

[image]

Also there is a WMI handle leak that I am just not able to isolate. I have already raised the handle quota several times (it's now set to 32k), but it still keeps crashing from time to time, which approves that there is a real handle leak and not only a load issue.

[image]

**Question**

How comes, that one GPO applies but the other one not? Both are using the **same** WMI filter!!!!